# Roll up project-level tasks to the project collection portal in TFS2010

Tags: tfs

I have a Project Collection setup in my TFS2010RC deployment. I have two Projects setup under this collection with their own task lists, which are populated with data.

I fully expected the tasks from these individual projects to "roll up" and appear in the task list at the Project Collection level, but they do not. The Project Collection task list is empty. Basically, I'm looking to provide a view so a supervisor could see all tasks across projects quickly and easily. I'm sure I could write a reporting services report, but it seems like this is something so basic that it would have been included and it just need to be turned on or something.

I'm sure I'm probably missing something really simple here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe I answered my own question.

I was mixed up with the difference between SharePoint "tasks" and TFS "work items" (which contain a Work_Item_Type of "task").

Once I resolved that misunderstanding, I simply added a "Query Results Web Part" in my Project Collection portal and modified the query to bring back tasks across all child projects.